# Use Theme.Dialog.AppError as parent in style definition

Tags: android

This is the XML code which is showing an error:

```
<style name="custom" parent="Theme.Dialog.AppError">
    <!-- it shows error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Dialog.AppError'-->.
</style>
```

Why can't I use Theme.Dialog.AppError as parent in style definition?

Comment: "Please help" should never be part of a good question. (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) on chit-chat)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Theme.Dialog.AppError

I think you are looking for

```
<style name="custom" parent="Theme.Micro.Dialog.AppError">
            ...
            </style>
```

Android source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values-watch/themes.xml

Comment: On this page https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml   scroll down till the end of the page its there under system themes.But lets say its Theme.Micro.Dialog.AppError still I cant use it as the parent of my custom style.Its throwing the same error as posted above.My question is why i cant use them.